# Access a base classes variable from within a child class

Tags: javascript, inheritance

In javascript is it possible for a child class to access & change a base class variable? If not is there a way to create a privileged variable? I know you can create privileged functions but what about privileged variables?

Here's my attempt:

```
  function BaseClass()
  {
     var privateMap = {"type": "BaseClass"};
  }

  function ChildClass()
  {
     // How can I access BaseClass's private variable privateMap?
     privateMap["type"] = "ChildClass";
  }

  ChildClass.prototype             = new BaseClass();
  ChildClass.prototype.constructor = ChildClass;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Base = function() 
  {
    var privateMap = {"type":"Base"};

    this.changeMap = function(arg) {
        privateMap['type'] = arg;
        console.log('Changed Map to ' + privateMap['type'])
    }

}
var Child = new Base;

Child.changeMap('Child1')

console.log(Child.privateMap)//undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna have to expose `privateMap` in `BaseClass`:

```
BaseClass.prototype.privateMap = {"type": "BaseClass"};
```

Then you access it in `ChildClass`:

```
BaseClass.prototype.privateMap["type"] = "ChildClass";
```